# vuefire- When I do orderBy () I lose the auto-sync

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex, vuefire

When I do ".orderBy('')" it no longer updates my list when I delete or do actions on it.
I do not understand what the problem is.

Without the orderBy ('') everything works fine, but I have to sort the list.

Would appreciate help

```
bindCycle: firestoreAction(({ state, bindFirestoreRef }) => {
  
  return bindFirestoreRef(
    'Cycle',
    fb.Cycle.where('Id', '==', state.Id).orderBy('done')
  )
}),
```

Comment: To start, is there an error message or debug output you can share?

Comment: There is no error message.
But I fixed it when I did "this. $ Store.dispatch ('bindCycle')" after every possible change